# Does SQL server log shipping require a 2nd SQL license

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2008, licensing, high-availability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I'm currently working on a high availability solution for SQL Server 2008.  I have 2 servers with 1 license of standard edition SQL Server.  Can you implement log shipping with just 1 license?  For example if you had SQL installed on the 2nd box, but not running, and the primary server ship logs to the backup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the SQL instance is used ONLY for purposes of receiving the log shipping (and no queries are executed against it), you do not need a second SQL license.  If you use that second server for snapshot reporting or any sort of querying at all, then a license would be required.

From the SQL Licensing FAQ: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/pricing-licensing-faq.aspx

Q.  If I am doing log shipping in an active/passive failover configuration, how should I license the backup server?

A. 
In this scenario, the passive server does not require a license, unless the passive server has more processors than the active server, and the active server is licensed under the per processor model.

And... with a pretty picture: http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/special-considerations.aspx#passive

Comment: Thanks! I'd been struggling to find a definitive answer reading through the licensing pages.

Comment: you'll still need to pay for a version of windows server unfortunately

Comment: I agree Nick. Fortunately, that's a lot cheaper than SQL Server though and can be utilized for running other bits, since the passive/backup SQL Server will not require many resources while it is standing by.

Comment: Beware, it has changed in recent versions. Quote: "Beginning with SQL 
Server 2014, each active server **licensed with SA coverage** allows the installation of a single passive server used for fail-over support."